# Visual Studio Code and Node.js using Coffee Script

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, visual-studio-code

I have an old node.js project I wanted to use for trying out VSCode. I run it usually by running "coffee app.coffee" from the command line. I've configured my launch.json file, but VSCode runs "node app.coffee" instead. How can I tell it to use coffee instead of node?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0):

The only configuration types supported at the moment appear to be node and mono. I understand that typescript support was included in one of the previews and will be returning when stable. No idea about a potential CoffeeScript timeline but I hope it's mapped, I really do.

Comment: Node is fine, right? My coffeescript is node. It's just not node using JavaScript. Is only node using JavaScript supported?

Comment: Yes. If you want a full coffeescript + node debuggable experience your best bet at the moment is probably IntelliJ IDEA